# What converges the series?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum _{n=4}^{+\infty \:}\frac{4^n\sqrt{n+1}-4^n\sqrt{n}+2^{n-1}\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}{4^n\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}$$

I tried different ways to figure this out and at first i did integrals 
$$\int _4^{\infty \:}\frac{4^x\sqrt{x+1}-4^x\sqrt{x}+2^{x-1}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}{4^x\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$

THEN 
$=0-\left(4-2\cdot \sqrt{5}-\frac{1}{32\ln \left(2\right)}\right)$

But then i realized it wasn't with integrals and that I can't do convergence D:

I just had to figure out what exactly converges the series without using integrals so I just exploded my brain with everything i did before.

Comment: How did you convert it into that integral?.

Comment: There's a reason why my name is Badatcalc :/

Comment: I recommend you read some material on Riemann Integration and Riemann sum, either some Calculus or  Analysis books or in the internet.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely will! I was out for the week of the lesson, so right now its just a struggle to catch up on things i generally don't understand. :/  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the general term is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^n}.$$

The sum $\displaystyle\sum_4^\infty \frac{1}{2\cdot 2^n}$ is a geometric series, and the sum $\displaystyle\sum_4^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$ telescopes.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum _{n=4}^{+\infty \:}\frac{4^n\sqrt{n+1}-4^n\sqrt{n}+2^{n-1}\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}{4^n\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} =\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right) +\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} +\frac{1}{16}$$